# Add Enum values to observableArrayList.with lambdas

Tags: java, lambda, enums

I'm programming in Java and want to add all values of an Enum to an `FXCollections.observableArrayList` which will be used to fill a ComboBox.
It works fine with the following code:

```
for(OutputType t : OutputType.values()) {
  outputTypes.add(t.toString());
}
```

How can I do that with a one liner using lambdas?

Comment: Why one liner? Your code is readable, don't ruin it.

Comment: So you'd prefer that over the oneliner below?

Comment: If I already wrote it I won't waste time trying to oneline it.

Comment: Yes I understand that, just want to try lambdas becaues I haven't used them much, and tehre are cases where they are way shorter.

Comment: I understand that, but you should consider other things than number of lines (performance, readability, etc..)

Comment: @Pabi  Yes, in this case I would rather use your original code instead, coz it run faster and produce no extra temp object, and it is equally, if not more, readable than the one-liner

Comment: A one-liner: [`outputTypes.addAll(OutputType.values());`](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/collections/ObservableList.html#addAll(E...))

Comment: @Holger you missed the `toString()`

Comment: Having strings in the data model instead of the actual `enum` values looks like a design error in the first place, causing the need to convert between strings and the actual type back and forth. Renderers call `toString` anyway.

Comment: Thanks Holger I didn't know that. That saves quite a few conversions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Arrays.stream(OutputType.values()).forEach(o -> outputTypes.add(o.toString()));
```

Comment: Thanks, that even saves the conversion to a List.

Comment: @Pabi: In such aspect, there is actually not much difference, as `Arrays.asList()` is just returning a thin wrapper (`Arrays.ArrayList`) of the array, which is similar for the case of `Arrays.stream(Object[])`.  It turns out that your original code is the best in such aspect as no extra object is created

Answer (score 0):

Well, figured it out. The problem was `OutputType.values()` returns an Array.
So with `Arrays.asList()` I'm able to use `.forEach()`:

```
Arrays.asList(OutputType.values()).forEach( OutputType -> outputTypes.add(OutputType.toString()));
```

Comment: Please note the naming convention

Comment: Which convention am I missing?

Comment: variable/parameter name should be in `camelCase` instead of `PascalCase`